# TypeScript error: "(property) has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor" when using a Union

Tags: typescript

[Here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAQwB7AgZzgMyhEcBEyqa+A3ALABQVAxgDYJoYCyAngMINNwDeVccYABMApgDsYwTMBoJJEMcwiiAXAQAyEAObAx+OAB8CAdRF0auEfqP4ASiJ1oYIqGX5wArmhdiEIEWpOULpacAC8BG7UlAI0UCJyIkIAFACUvO4CROgAdFoiMMn4APReLvipOTAAFuLJyfFoaghirOlhAHwZMQK9NcBoOWVQvv7hcI05QnIIQ94jfiIUPb1w-YPC4pLSsvKKyiLj+KbmllGrAL6pywIXVO7VLUJ0IppaEB6F6Xwra9UDOU2EikMjkqH2oiOb105zgd2iAkeYmer20umSYAQUD8gRgwTEWm+mT+AOGo0OEUx2JAVQgAFUwGAXOxGCI0jc+v8NqJgTswQolJCIsczBZ-LD4RcgA)'s a TS playground link. I get the error above on `identificationMode` when having `strictNullChecks` and `strictPropertyInitialization` checked. It disappears if I declare it as this: `identificationMode: string = "Login"` but then I lose the spell checking that comes with using a Union to define the set of strings that `identificationMode` is allowed to be.

```
import axios from "axios";

class MyClass {
  identificationMode: "Login" | "Welcome" | "Register";
  username: string = "";

  created() {
    axios.get("/user").then((res: any) => {
      this.username = res.data.username;
      this.identificationMode = "Welcome";
    });
  }

  handleLogout() {
    this.identificationMode = "Login";
  }

  handleLogin(param: string) {
    this.username = param.toUpperCase();
    this.identificationMode = "Welcome";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the union type as your type annotation along with an initial value for the desired effect

```
identificationMode: "Login" | "Welcome" | "Register" = "Login";
```

Answer (score 1):

That union implies that the property CAN'T be undefined. So either you define its value right away (or in a constructor) OR you add to the union the 'undefined', like this:

```
identificationMode: "Login" | "Welcome" | "Register" = "Login"; // Assign immediately
```

or:

```
identificationMode: "Login" | "Welcome" | "Register" | undefined;
```

Either way should give you the right result but, in my opinion, the second one would be more correct if you don't want the property to have a value when you create an object from that class.